# window.scrollTo is not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the scrollbar to be positioned on top by default as soon as I launch the page.But the below code works fine in chrome but not in IE11.

If I try to debug the script, the scrollbar is positioned on top.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
 }
```

I tried different solution online such as

```
$(window).scroll().scrollTop(0);
document.body.scrollTop(0);
```

But nothing worked in IE.Kindly help me

Comment: If I remember correctly, `setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,0);},1);` will do the trick.

Comment: I also vaguely remember either Android or iOS not being able to scroll to `0`, but scrolling to `1` will work.

Comment: I tried ur function still am facing the same issue in IE11

Answer (score 4):

Though this is a very old question, but updating here for someone looking for a solution.

Try using:

```
element.scrollTop = 0;
```

This should work on all browsers.

Comment: Define how you are getting 'element'. Are you still using jQuery for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```js
$('body,html').scroll().scrollTop(0);
```

or

```js
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0});
```

Comment: I tried your code.But still it didn't work in IE. Also I cleared the browser cache. Still I am facing the same issue