# scrollTo is not a a method defined in Internet Explorer 11 (for scrolling an element into the middle of the view)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I wrote a method which scrolls a container to an element within it, but keeps the element in the middle of the view. It looks like this:

```
// Function for scrolling to an element, and placing it in the middle of the view
// By default, the container parameter is set to the browser window
function scrollIntoViewMiddle(element, container) {
    if (container === undefined) {
        container = window;
    }
    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top;
    var middleDiff = (elementRect.height / 2);
    var scrollTopOfElement = absoluteElementTop + middleDiff;
    var scrollY = scrollTopOfElement - (window.innerHeight / 2);
    container.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
}
```

This works on most browsers, even some old FF ones. However, on Internet Explorer 11, I get the error in the title, that `scrollTo()` is not a defined function. What could be an alternative to this function for IE11? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Try `container.scrollTop = scrollY;` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60706367/9180619

Comment: @l-portet Nope doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with l-portet, Since [the scrollTo method doesn't support IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo), we could set the [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) property and [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) property to achieve the same effect.

Besides, the issue also related to the following code:

```
var scrollY = scrollTopOfElement - (window.innerHeight / 2);
```

I think you want to get the scrollY based on the target element and the container element, instead of the window element. So, please try to modify your code as below:

```
    function scrollIntoViewMiddle(element, container) {
        if (container === undefined) {
            container = window;
        }
        var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top;
        var middleDiff = (elementRect.height / 2);
        var scrollTopOfElement = absoluteElementTop + middleDiff;
        var scrollY = (scrollTopOfElement - (container.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2));
        //container.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
        container.scrollLeft = 0;
        container.scrollTop = scrollY;
    }
```

More details sample code, please check [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/L6gnq21c/).

Besides, here is another workaround, it uses JQuery animate and scrollto, you could refer it.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery(document).on('click', '#scroll_button', function (e) {

            var el = $("#scroll_test");
            var elOffset = el.offset().top;
            var elHeight = el.outerHeight();
            var frameHeight = $("#editor").outerHeight();
            var offset;

            if (elHeight < frameHeight) {
                offset = elOffset - ((frameHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
            }
            else {
                offset = elOffset;
            }


            jQuery('#editor').animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            }, 1000);
        });

    });
</script>
<style>
    #editor {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #scroll_test {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>
<div id="editor" placeholder="Enter text ..." contenteditable="true" autofocus>
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <div id="scroll_test">
        test
    </div>
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
    <span>content</span><br />
</div>
<button id="scroll_button">
    Scroll
</button>
```

The result looks as below:

[image]